# Angular 6 htttp POST - setting params as query string in URL

Tags: angular, http-post, angular6

I have an applicataion based on asp .net core boilerplate.
I need to send http POST parameters from my Angular 6 app.

My service looks like this:

```
public findProduct(productCode: string) {
const url_ = 'api/product/findProduct';
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('productCode', productCode);

return this.http.post(url_, params, httpHeaders)
  .subscribe(
    result => {
      console.log(result);
    },
    error => {
      console.log('There was an error: ')
    }
  );
```

I have imported URLSearchParams from @angular/http, but still I have the same problem. My POST URL is bad, because API expect POST URL like this:
**http://localhost:21021/api/product/findProduct?productCode=1111** and query string parameters like:
**productCode: 1111**

but mine looks like this:
**http://localhost:21021/api/product/findProduct**
and setting request payload (always empty):

```
**{rawParams: "", queryEncoder: {}, paramsMap: {}}
paramsMap: {}
queryEncoder: {}
rawParams: ""**
```

My httpHeaders is:
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'text/plain'

My question is how can I set expected API POST parameters in this service?

Comment: Your problem or one of your problem is that you have ulr_, and url_ you never specify your server where are you specifying the localhost?

Comment: It's my missing in this post. But thanks ;)

Comment: also correct me if I'm wrong but it seems you are passing an empty const params

Comment: Are you sure this is a post? sounds like a get to me but i could be wrong

Comment: It's example only. I am assing params. And, yes it's POST. I know that it'll be GET, but I'm not backend developer :)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you want. The "params" are not the params to be passed as a part of the URL string like you are thinking, that for GET only. Take a look to the difference between post and get. https://www.diffen.com/difference/GET-vs-POST-HTTP-Requests

Comment: But swagger can do it.. I don't know how..
https://swagger.io/

Comment: haven't heard of it. So if you can do it using swagger only or other tool ONLY that means is not native to http

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
We have to pass params as 3rd parameter for post request   


 public findProduct(productCode: string) {
    const url_ = 'api/product/findProduct';
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('productCode', productCode);

    return this.http.post(url_,,params, httpHeaders)
      .subscribe(
        result => {
          console.log(result);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('There was an error: ')
        }
      );
```